# I have Steema Teechart. How to see the minor tick values on axis?

Tags: c#, wpf, teechart

We are using Steema Tchart (version - 4.1.2012.1311) to show graph in C#, WPF. We want to show the minor tick values on Logarithmic axis. Ex: Logarithmic Y-axis with maximum = 100, minimum = 1, Minortickcount = 2, On Y-axis it should show the values of both major and minor tick values. Currently it is showing 1,10,100 with 2 minor ticks.

Expectation :
Current Logarithmic Y-axis shows labels 1,10,100 with 2 minor ticks. we want to see minor ticks      labels also along with major tick labels (1, 10, 100).